"10 years later" versus "10 years thereafter" versus "10 years after that"
Is there any difference between "10 years later", "10 years thereafter", and "10 years after that"? I found the following expressions exactly the same; the only difference is formality. Thereafter is probably more formal than the other two words.
Originally, I chose "ten years later". However, I was afraid that it might be mistakenly understood as 10 years after 1981, that's why I tried to look for other phrases. One might ask why I didn't simply use in 2001. The reason is that I'd repeatedly used in + year in my previous and following sentences, so I wanted to try something new. Also, I'm generally curious about the difference between these phrases.


15% of the school’s spending went into equipment in 1981, with a subsequent drop to 5% in 1991 and a sharp rise to 23% ten years thereafter. (I mean in 2001 in these examples)
15% of the school’s spending went into equipment in 1981, with a subsequent drop to 5% in 1991 and a sharp rise to 23% ten years after that.
15% of the school’s spending went into equipment in 1981, with a subsequent drop to 5% in 1991 and a sharp rise to 23% ten years later.


Also, should I include "then" as in "and then a sharp rise..." in these examples?

Do you think there’s a difference? Why or why not? What research have you done, and what have you learned from it?

I've added more details to my question.

All are correct, but "thereafter" is not as good as it adds a bit of cognitive strain. The other two are equally good.

Thank you! Is "then" needed here?

"thereafter" always is relative to the most recently mentioned time/year if you've mentioned more than one.

@TimR Do the other words have the same quality?

Yes, they will always be understood in relation to the most recently mentioned time if left unqualified.
